# Ruby Rails my link won't work on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, routes

I've been trying to deal with this to no avail.  It's driving me nuts.  Usually, I can sleep on something like this and realize it was a typo in the morning.  But I can't sleep until I figure this out - catch 22.  Anyway, I have an index of questions being displayed, the title of each question is a link to itself.  Nothing surprising there.  And it works on local host.  When I deploy to heroku, it shows that it's leading me to the correct link and I have it routed correctly when I hover the links.  (ie, myapp.herokuapp.com/questions/2).  I definitely have the links set to question_path(question) in the block.  yet, when I click the link, it takes me to the questions_path, right back to the index of questions.  It's driving me mad.  Anyone have a problem like this before?

**index.html.erb View:**

```
  <% if @quests.present? %>
      <% @quests.each do |question| %>
         <div class="booyah-box col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
         <center>
           <bptitle>
              <%= link_to question.qtitle.html_safe, question_path(question) %>
           </bptitle>
           <br />
           <bpauthor> A question by <%= question.user.firstname %> <%= question.user.lastname %>, from  
            <%= question.user.organization.name %></bpauthor>
        </center>
        <br />
        <%= question.qbody.split[0..10].join(" ").html_safe %>... <br /><br />
           Answers: <%= question.answers.count %><br />
        </div>
   <% end %>
   <% else %>
      <p>There are no posts containing the term(s) <%= params[:search] %>.</p>
   <% end %>   
       </center>
```

**questions_controller:**

```
 def index 
    if params[:search] != nil
       @quests = Question.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
       @quests = Question.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
 end

  def show
     @question = Question.find(params[:id])
     @answer = Answer.new
     @faveanswer = Favanswer.new
     @ans = Answer.find(params[:id])
     @qids = []
     @qaids = []
     Favanswer.all.each do |favanswer|

  @qids << favanswer.question_id
  @qaids << [favanswer.question_id, favanswer.answer_id]

end
end
```

**Question model:**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 include Bootsy::Container

 mount_uploader :bootsy, BootsyUploader

 belongs_to :user
 has_many :answers
 has_one :favanswer

 def self.search(search)
  where("qtitle LIKE ? OR qbody LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%") 
 end
end
```

Please tell me I have a typo.  I will kiss your feet if you help.  I need sleep.

Editing with my heroku logs per Andrew's comment below:

```
2016-08-01T13:54:20.800626+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/questions/3" for     162.244.49.116 at 2016-08-01 13:54:20 +0000
2016-08-01T13:54:20.803208+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by     QuestionsController#show as HTML
2016-08-01T13:54:20.803238+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
2016-08-01T13:54:20.806102+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT   "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1   [["id", 1]]
2016-08-01T13:54:20.809813+00:00 app[web.1]:   Question Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
2016-08-01T13:54:20.833346+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to     http://mypretendapp.herokuapp.com/questions
```

Comment: What does your log say in heroku? Any notes about redirecting to the index method? How about `rescue_from` methods? Could anything be redirecting you due to a not found due to bad data on heroku?

Comment: Can someone answer this? I'm stuck on it too.

I have a loop. And 
<%= link_to service.website, service.website, :target => '_blank', rel: "nofollow" %> is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Heroku configuration, you can either face a `404` error or being redirected (to home by default if I remember well) when the page you're looking for does not exist (either the routing is bad or your controller raises a `ActiveRecordNotFound` error). If it works in localhost, I would rather explore my second guess. You should check your `question` object that you are passing to your url helper. Is it correct ? Does it have an id ?

Comment: I don't think this is it, either.  The question object is right, confirmed by the link showing up when I hover the link, and by the heroku logs I added above.  The route is showing this, `question GET    /questions/:id(.:format)                                questions#show`

Comment: Did your use debugger to inspect your vars in your show method ? All your variables are fine ? Escpecially `@question` and `@ans` using `find`.

Comment: *smooch*  Many, many, many mahalos my friend.  I was so focused on the question variables I didn't look elsewhere.  Great call - it was that pointless @ans variable.  I don't know how it ended up there or why I had it in the first place.  But, it was raising an `ActiveRecordNotFound` error.  Hopefully, this thread will be useful to someone else someday!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the variable `question` in

```
<%= link_to question.qtitle.html_safe, question_path(question) %>
```

with `@question`? If I'm reading it correctly, it would be pointing it back at `@quests` because of your do loop instead of `@question`.

Comment: That's not it. `@quests` refers to all questions, so the block refers to `@quests.each`, so it's saying for each object in `@quests` (the questions) do this action and I'm going to refer to each object as "question" in the loop.  `@question` doesn't exist per my index.  `@quests` used to be `@question`, but I was getting confused in the blocks like this so I just changed it to help myself out.